# Java: WatchService : File.Lastmodified returns 0

Tags: java

I am trying to write a basic directory monitor that prints whether a file is created, changed, or deleted. But I am having trouble displaying the 'lastModified' time of each file. Please see full code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

    Path dir = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\test");

    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher,

            StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
            StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
            StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY
            );

    for (;;) {


        WatchKey key2 = watcher.take(); 

        for ( WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()  ) {

            WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();


            WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event; 

            Path filename = ev.context(); 
            File fullFilename = filename.toFile();

            System.out.println("Event: |"+kind+"| Filename: "+fullFilename.getName()+"|Time: "+fullFilename.lastModified());


            if (fullFilename.exists()) {


                System.out.println(fullFilename.getName()+" - Exists");

            }

            else {

                System.out.println("fullFileName does not exist");

            }

        }


        boolean valid = key.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            break;
        }
    }


}
```

The `lastModified` method returns 0. I have tried testing whether `fileFullname` object actually exists, and for some reason it doesn't. Yet, when you use `fileFullname.getName()` it returns the filename just fine.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I appreciate your help, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need resolve the filename against the watched directory.

You can not get the `lastModified` value because the context filesystem of the event does not have your watched directory as `defaultDirectory`, the `defaultDirectory` is the directory from the app runs, if you check the existence of `fullFilename` you will get `false`

```
Path filename = ev.context(); 
File fullFilename = filename.toFile();
//fullFilename.exists(); returns false
```

so you need resolve it by this way

```
Path name = (Path) event.context();
//dir is you watched directory
File filename = dir.resolve(name).toFile();
```

The complete code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Path pathToWatch = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\tmp\\test");
        try (WatchService watchService = pathToWatch.getFileSystem().newWatchService()) {
            Path dir = Paths.get("C:\\tmp\\test");
            dir.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);
            WatchKey key = watchService.take();
            do {
                for (final WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    Path name = (Path) event.context();
                    File filename = dir.resolve(name).toFile();
                    System.out.println(dir + ": " + event.kind() + ": " + event.context() + ", Modified: " + filename.lastModified());
                }
            } while (key.reset());
        }
    }
}
```

More information at [docs.oracle.com (Watching a Directory for Changes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This was helpful and has solved my issue.
Thank you very much for your help!