# Get only new files in a directory with Java

Tags: java, file, comparator

I have a timer that looks at a certain directory each hour and pull the contents of that directory for processing.  To remove 24 hour duplication, I'm trying to figure out a way to only pull 'new' files for processing.  ("new" being older than 24 hours).

One option is to write a custom Comparator, but I was looking for any other alternative ways.

Idea's or thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: A full example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310838/java-watchservice-file-lastmodified-returns-0/21315743#21315743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found what I was looking for with commons-io:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1 * -1);  
Date yesterday = cal.getTime();   
System.out.println(yesterday);       

// Test for newer files (2nd param [false] = get newer files)        
String[] files = dir.list( new AgeFileFilter(yesterday,false) );
for ( int i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
    System.out.println(files[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid issues with file system time stamp differences I would just put in a folder called something like "processed" and move the files you are done with there.  That way you can just read what ever files are present.

Answer (score 0):

Hash the file paths to a map and store with it the time you first time encountered it.

Comment: Wouldn't they lose their list of files already processed every time they restart the service?

Comment: Well there's no mention of there being a service of any kind that will be restarted or what kind of environment this program is running in, so I provided a bare bones solution that can be built upon.